# Building a Custom Parser

Tags: python, csv, parsing

Absolutely New to Parsing. How to build a custom parser from scratch ?

I have a csv file which has lines as follows
`ADD UTYPRABTOAW:LOGICRNCID=253, RABINDEX=1, DELAYCLASS=3, TOAWS=35, TOAWE=8;`

I want the relevant values retained and everything else removed

I want the line above to be converted to `253,1,3,35,8`.

I stumbled on to the concept of parsing in Python, but I am looking for a starting point.
I have 150 separate `csv` files and for each I will have to build a separate parser.

Comment: Hi. Can you provide any code you have tried so far?

Comment: pyparsing is an easy-to-get-started-with-parsing Python library (disclaimer: I wrote pyparsing)

Comment: Hey Nick, as of now the code is pretty simple

df = pd.read_table('my_file.txt',header=None)

All the lines are imported into a dataframe, but then instead of looping through the lines, I am trying to explore parsing. Once parsed, I want to export them into a database or a text file.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include what the script will need to do? e.g. read each CSV from a folder and combine? Convert each to CSV? Do all of your files have the same format?

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression could be used to extract the numbers, but it really depends on the full format of the file you are trying to parse. If your input file looks as follows:

```
ADD UTYPRABTOAW:LOGICRNCID=253, RABINDEX=1, DELAYCLASS=3, TOAWS=35, TOAWE=8;
ADD UTYPRABTOAW:LOGICRNCID=253, RABINDEX=2, DELAYCLASS=3, TOAWS=35, TOAWE=8;
ADD UTYPRABTOAW:LOGICRNCID=253, RABINDEX=3, DELAYCLASS=3, TOAWS=35, TOAWE=8;
```

Then the following script would easily convert it into your required output CSV format:

```
import re
import csv

with open('input.csv', newline='') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    for row in f_input:
        csv_output.writerow(re.findall(r"\d+", row))
```

i.e. `output.csv` would be:

```
253,1,3,35,8
253,2,3,35,8
253,3,3,35,8
```

The `glob` library could be used to carry out this process on all matching files in a given folder, for example all CSV files starting with the name `input` e.g. `input*.csv`. Also if your files contain other lines that are not required, then you would need to add a condition e.g. `if row.startswith('ADD'):`

```
import re
import csv
import glob

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    for filename in glob.glob('input*.csv'):
        with open(filename, newline='') as f_input:
            for row in f_input:
                if row.startswith('ADD'):
                    csv_output.writerow(re.findall(r"\d+", row))
```